# excel display decimal as percentage?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that will allow me to convert a decimal to a percentage.

Let me explain.

If a user enters a decimal between 0.1 to 0.10 These should display as negative percentages, i.e. -10% to -100%

Then 1.1 to 1.10 should display as 10% to %100.

Can someone please show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: "decimal between 0.1 to 0.10": There is not any value between 0.1 and 0.10. These values are equal: `0.1 = 0.10`. Same with 1.1 and 1.10.

Comment: Can you show a list of possible inputs, expected outputs and the rationale for how one becomes the other?  I'm totally not getting what you want to happen and why.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage representation in Excel is created with formatting. For values between -100% to 100%, the underlying number is a value between -1 and 0 for negative percentages and between 0 and 1 for positive percentages.

Assuming there's a typo in your question and you want values between 0 and 1 to show as a negative percentage, whereas values between 1 and 2 should show as positive percentages: This cannot be done with formatting alone. Formatting cannot change the value of a number.

You will need to use a formula to subtract a 1 from the value and then format the result as a percentage.

[image]